# sending messages over winsock for irc ident

Tags: powershell, irc

I'm just began writing an IRC bot and I'm having some problems sending the ident, here is part of my code that i'm having the issue with:

```
   $nick = "bot1818"
   $writer.AutoFlush = $true
   $writer.NewLine   = $true
   $writer.WriteLine("USER $nick 0 * :$nick bot")
```

I'm getting a ":morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response" shortly after that i'm disconnected.

Comment: How did you define `$writer`?

Comment: `$stream = $socket.GetStream()`
`$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream`

Answer (score 0):

You're not registering the connection properly.

You need to send a `NICK` message as well as the `USER` message, so somthing like this:

```
$writer.WriteLine("NICK $nick")
```

Don't worry about the "No Ident response", it's an ancient technology and is not needed to connect to most IRC networks these days, and wouldn't be provided by Windows systems anyway.

I recommend you have a read of [RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459) - it will tell you everything you need to know about the IRC protocol.